# Heroku node_modules not cached

Tags: heroku, npm, node-modules, buildpack

I have toplevel package.json where I set cacheDirectories as per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#custom-caching

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm --prefix frontend start && npm --prefix mockserver start",
},
"dependencies": {
},
"devDependencies": {
},
"cacheDirectories": ["frontend/node_modules", "mockserver/node_modules"],
...
```

So no dependencies in toplevel, but I have frontend/package.json and mockserver/package.json with a lot of dependencies that get installed in their respective node_modules. This is how the respective package.jsons look like (for example mockserver):

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm install && npm run build && node dist/server.js",
 },
 dependencies...
 devdependencies...
```

This works fine and deploys, but it does not cache the the two node_modules defined to be cached.

Here is the output from heroku build:

```
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=demo
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true

       npm scripts will see NODE_ENV=production (not 'demo')
       https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#production
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  7.10.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Downloading and installing node 7.10.0...
       Using default npm version: 4.2.0
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (package.json):
       - frontend/node_modules (not cached - skipping)
       - mockserver/node_modules (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (package.json):
       - frontend/node_modules (nothing to cache)
       - mockserver/node_modules (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
```

Just to note that the two node_modules were installed in the previous build but it says (not cached - skipping).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/issues/435

In summary, I should have used heroku-postbuild instead of start script to install custom dependencies. And use start only as application starting command.

Top level package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm --prefix frontend run installAndCompile && npm --prefix mockserver run installAndCompile",
    "start": "npm --prefix mockserver start"
  },
```

Subproject's package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "installAndCompile": "npm install && npm run compile"
  },
```